# XmlReader from stored procedure with for xml raw, root returns nothing

Tags: .net, sql-server

Where I run the procedure below in SSMS it works fine and returns nicely formatted XML, as shown below. When I call in from .NET, however, it returns an empty zero-length string.

```
exec usp_posStrategyGet
```

returns the following result

```
<root><row>stuff</row></root>
```

Below is the code in .NET. This code has been working for years it only stopped working when I deployed the code and database to a new Windows 10 development environment which makes me think there is something wrong with the new system, but I deployed it to another Windows 10 dev environment and the same thing happened.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;

public static string posStrategyGetXml()
{
    string ffdconx = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ffdconx"];
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ffdconx);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_posStrategyGet");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();
    
    XmlReader myXmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
    myXmlReader.MoveToContent();

    string myXmlNodeString;
    StringBuilder myXmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (!myXmlReader.EOF)
    {
        myXmlNodeString = myXmlReader.ReadOuterXml();
        myXmlStringBuilder = myXmlStringBuilder.Append(myXmlNodeString);
    }

    string myXmlString = myXmlStringBuilder.ToString();

    myXmlReader.Close();
    conn.Close();

    return myXmlString;
}
```

and here is the simple procedure that I'm calling

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[usp_posStrategyGet]
as
set nocount on

select ghandiType, c.team, g.subpos
, CONVERT(CHAR(10),startdate,126) startdate
, CONVERT(CHAR(10),enddate,126) enddate
,  playerAffected
from ghandi_x_team g
join tblTeamCity c
on g.qs_tmid = c.qs_tmid
where 1=1
and enddate >=dbo.udf_getNextGameDate (getdate())
order by team, ghandiType, startdate, enddate

for xml raw,root
```

Comment: Aside... [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection), [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand) and [System.Xml.XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader) are all `IDisposable` classes and should be declared/consumed in `using` blocks. i.e.: the above code will likely be leaking memory and connection resources.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `usp_posStrategyGet` you're deploying to the new instances is exactly the same as the `usp_posStrategyGet` deployed to previous instances?

Comment: Does the `usp_posStrategyGet` use `FOR XML` and if so does it have `, TYPE` parameter?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes its the same one.  its in a repository.  the code hasn't changed in years.

Comment: @Charlieface I've included the simple proc code

Comment: The only thing I can think is that it's bugging out on the (rather strange) way that `FOR XML` without `,TYPE` returns: it returns separate rows for every 2033 characters. Try adding `,TYPE` and see what you get

Comment: @Charlieface that did it.  Please answer the question and I'll select your response.  I'm not sure what it did, but immediately after adding type .Net pulled the xml.  I even undid the change and it still worked.  Wierd.  I ran profiler for before and after comparison and after there were about 10% fewer reads.  Not sure what that means other than something was different even though nothing in the query select statement itself had changed, only the xml 'type' variable had been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR XML` has a weird output. If `, TYPE` is specified, or it is put into a subquery or variable, then the whole XML is output as a single value.

But if `, TYPE` is not specified, and `FOR XML` is top-level (no subqueries), then the XML is split into separate `nvarchar` rows of 2033 characters each.

Using `ExecuteXmlReader` is supposed to fix that, by concatenating it all together. But it is possible that something is making that not happen properly.

You can therefore fix this by either putting it into a subquery

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT ...
    ...
    FOR XML ...
)
```

Or you can add `, TYPE`, which will return an `xml` typed value.

If you are just reading it as a string then probably best to go with the first option, and you can now remove most of that C# code.

```cs
public static string posStrategyGetXml()
{
    string ffdconx = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ffdconx"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ffdconx))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_posStrategyGet", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        var myXmlString = (string)comm.ExecuteScalar();
        return myXmlString;
    }
}
```

Note also correct use of `using` to dispose the connection and command.

Comment: this worked for my dev sql 2019 computer, but when I pushed the fix to my prod sql 2014 server it didn't work.   This is so wierd because this code has worked great for years.

Comment: Then there is probably no rows to return. Try running the `SELECT` without `FOR XML` and see what you get

Comment: there are two rows returned

Comment: I moved the db to sql 2019 and still getting the bug.  There are two rows but .net gets nothing...empty string, no exception.

Comment: There is something weird going on. I've never seen such a thing happen and I've used this type of code many times before. Are you sure you are connecting to the right database and schema, is it even a different server? Did you actually use the code I showed: `SELECT (SELECT ... FOR XML ...);` Is there perhaps another `SELECT` statement in your proc? Do you have some kind of non-deterministic condition in your query, like a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I'm running profiler on the target db and I can see the activity happening.  I didn't encase the 'for xml' inside parenthesis, so I'll try that.  I do have an order by so I'll try dropping that, too.

Comment: I put the for xml inside the parens, removed the order by, but no luck, I even blew away the plan cache to make sure I wasn't hitting an old cached version of the proc and I included the with recompile option to make double sure.  Ran profiler on the target server to make sure it was hitting the right server, but no luck.

Comment: Are you perhaps passing parameters (which you haven't shown) or is there anything else in the procedure that you haven't shown? Are you running under a different user and using Row Level Security?

Comment: I just redeployed the .net project to production in such a way that it could be debugged.  Now I can see that it is returning the xml and not an empty string and so your fix did work, at least partially.  Its not being rendered in the client and so I think it may be serializing-deserializing differently, but I can fix.